# Is there a way to make sure that the labels on my graph dont overlap with each other other than ggrepel as that seems to run forever

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, overlap, ggrepel

I'm trying to make sure that the district labels don't overlap on my graph as they are kinda congested and too many. However, using geom_text_repel produces no results even when I let it run for hours. Please help me out I have been stuck on this for so long. I have attached the picture for when I use the simple geom_text( without the repel)

```
    w <-  map_and_data%>%
  group_by(districts)%>%
  mutate(avgterror=mean(Typetattacksmilitants)*100)

options(ggrepel.max.overlaps = Inf)

n <- ggplot(w,aes(total,avgterror,label=districts)) + geom_point() +
  labs( title = "Relationship between Average Number of Terrorist attacks and Frequency of Cellphone Shutdowns",
        caption="Grouped by District",
        x="Frequency of Cellphone Shutdowns",
        y="Average number of Terrorist Attacks") +
 geom_text_repel(aes(label=districts))
```

This is my plot with overlaps

[image]

Comment: Looking at the graph, I think it might help to log-transform both axes to space out the labels near the origins somewhat. (Assuming all the xy-coordinates are between [0,Inf])

Comment: You could also try `geom_jitter` to move points around, but you have to be careful as it distorts the data. I would recommend perhaps taking out the y=0 (or low volume) data and visualising them separately. Really depends on what question you want to answer with the graph. Also with `ggrepel.max.overlaps`, maybe try lowering this and accept some overlaps, see if there is a suitable trade-off between accuracy and time